# Using MS Test ClassInitialize() and TestInitialize() in VS2010 as opposed to NUnit

Tags: nunit, mstest

I've used NUnit with VS2008, and now am adapting to MSTest on VS2010.  I used to be able to create an object in TestSetup() and dispose of it in TestCleanup(), and have the object created each time a test method was run in NUnit, preventing me from duplicating the code in each test method.

Is this not possible with MSTest?  The examples I am finding using the ClassInitialize and ClassCleanup and TestInitialize and TestCleanup attributes only show how to write to the console.  None show any more detailed use of these attributes.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here is a simple example using TestInitialize and TestCleanup.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private NorthwindEntities context;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        this.context = new NorthwindEntities();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(92, this.context.Customers.Count());
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        this.context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom.  Am I correct in assuming that NorthwindEntities is a referenced assembly in the test project?

Comment: Yes, it was in a referenced assembly.

Comment: Note that TestInitialize and TestCleanup methods must be marked as **public**, as shown.

Comment: Also note: if TestInitialize throws an exception then TestCleanup is *not* called. So while the code above is correct, adding any code after creating the context that could throw will necessitate a `try { ... } catch { TestCleanUp(); throw; }` block.